# How can I execute Graphql query?

Tags: c#, .net, graphql

Please, give an easy example how to execute query. I found some examples on the net but they are not working.

Like

```
GraphqlClient client = new GraphqlClient("example.com\graphql");
String query = "query {getClient(condition){clientName, clientID}}"
var response = client.executeQuery(query);
```

Comment: Is that an example you've actually tried? Did you replace `condition` with the condition you're searching for?

Comment: Adding to what @DarrenLamb said, did you change the graphql endpoint in your snippet?

Comment: I just want to find some graphql queries examples using c#.

Comment: There is a nuget GraphQL.Client. How i can execute SendQueryAsync without defining a type of object?

Comment: https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-client#operationname-and-variables-request
Just use JObject if class for data is not definied 
var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<JObject>(personAndFilmsRequest);

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine:

```
var graphQLOptions = new GraphQLHttpClientOptions
        {
            EndPoint = new Uri("example.com\graphql", UriKind.Absolute),
        };
       var graphQLClient = new GraphQLHttpClient(graphQLOptions, new NewtonsoftJsonSerializer());

       var msg = new GraphQLRequest
        {
            Query = "query {getClient(condition){clientName, clientID}}"
        };
       var graphQLResponse = await graphQLClient.SendQueryAsync<dynamic>(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
```